# shelf life for chilli sauce

Tags: chili-peppers

I have made a chilli jam and it did not set so I thought I could use it as a hot dipping or stir fry sauce.  If I open the jars and tip it into glass bottles How Long would the shelf life be

Comment: Howdy!  In the future, you can get more detailed answers if you provide information like the recipe you were using.

Answer (score 2):

Unless the chili sauce consists of 20% or more vinegar, it [needs to be refrigerated](https://pepperscale.com/does-sweet-chili-sauce-need-to-be-refrigerated/) after opening.  This is true regardless of whether you originally made it as jam.

Given that, I'd advise leaving it in the heat-sealed jars until you want to use it.

Comment: There are companies that sell alternate lids to use with mason jars.  I’ve seen some that give a bottle-like too that you could use to avoid needing to transfer the contents.  I can’t recommend any specific products, as I’ve never used them, but as an example: https://www.amazon.com//dp/B097M8XSS2/

Comment: ... with the warning of don't swap lids until you're ready to put the leftovers in the fridge.

Comment: Right, if they’re currently processed to be shelf stable, only change to the bottle top type lid when you want to use it